# Hide the icon of chrome packaged app when running？

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm trying to make a chrome packaged app，and I want to hide the icons in the taskbar when it is launched!

I was searching for a long time, but I still can't finish this. Is there any way or API to achieve this?

Comment: it's impossible now. even the chromium window manager doesn't support it.